# Is the blockchain crossplatform?

Tags: blockchain

I have the full client running in a local Windows machine but I want to move it to a VPS with Linux.  Will I need to download the whole blockchain again or can I just upload the copy I have on the pc?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the blk*.dat files are just the raw block data, so they should be the same on all platforms.  You'll probably have to regenerate the databases (`-reindex`) which may take quite a while.

Note that Bitcoin Core needs a couple gigabytes of RAM to run well, which is more than most cheap VPSes come with.  And of course the 120+ GB of disk space for the blockchain data itself.

Comment: The database should be compatible across platforms too.